# Is there a limit for Edit

Tags: discussion, editing

Today I notice one user this user gain nearly 100 reputation from edit today.

Personally I don't Have any issue with edit If edit is good, But changing one spelling everytime cannot be a good and specially if you edit same spelling all over the website.

Because my main reason for this is If a user don't know single thing about magento he/she can earn 2000 reputation from edit only and this way they can quickly earn 2000 reputation.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/47824/tetrixuser?tab=reputation

And earning from edit only also not good Because from editing you are not providing new things to community.

and this user earns 1000 reputation at stackoverflow.com By just editing.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/6315209/tetrixuser?tab=reputation

So is this kind of behavior allowed ??

and also want to know Is there a limit for per day  editing? because as reviewer we can  review 20  posts.

Comment: This feels to me like an instance where the voting system has failed (enough for me to comment on it); I think the best answer is a combination of two of the current lowest-scoring answers, [Dan's](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1112/) and [Julien's](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1099/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Good question, I was going to ask something along these lines as well. So I can't give you a definite answer, but my opinion:

I consider searching for common spelling errors to edit them bad behavior to game the reputation system, as it does not improve the content remarkably:

- If there is nothing else to improve in a post, it's not worth an edit.
- If the post has more issues, an edit should address these as far as possible. A single corrected typo alone won't help
- If you are below 2000 (?) rep, you get reputation for these edits **and** waste the time of three reviewers.

Comment: Yes I want tell the same Because from last  2 hours I am skipping his suggestions,  because if I reject and some other guy has made good edit then at that time I don't have privilege  for accepting their edits

Comment: I´m correcting spelling errors like Magneto to Magento but not for the reputation just for the sake of spelling it right. But if that´s not something people care about then i might as well stop doing it :-) Good to know

Comment: @klettseb as soon as you have enough reputation to edit without review, it matters less. And correcting is not bad per se, just don't search for one typo and leave ten uncorrected

Comment: @Klettseb I think you should continue your reviews. You are making the content of this site more readable which is also a good contribution to the community. Please remember CONTENT IS THE KING. Do not hesitate to do that again. :)

Answer (score 5):

I think it's the reviewer's responsibility to not let these kind of useless (although correct) minor changes be published and would also prevent necroposting.

Comment: If the edit was proper and genuine  then reviewer must have to allow that. But the point is what if the edits are too much from any user ?
I think we don't allow reputation after certain edit limit in a day.

Comment: we have limit on reputation that you can earn 200 reputation per day. but if someone earning 200rep perday by just editing is not good b'coz in our site 200rep per day is big thing and if you are doing just by editing I dont think its good, may we have some limit that per day you can earn 30-40 rep by editing for rest of the edit you can do edit but you cannot get points after 15-20 edits, that should gonna be do.

Answer (score 4):

**5 hours** and **120 rep** wow good speedy work. actually problem is that we only see the edit not who is editing this and off-course reviewer have no time for that too in my opinion . I think this blog post will answer your question.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253084/is-there-no-limit-to-edits-you-can-make-in-a-day-rep-farming

This user had 60 edit suggestions approved, and 0 edit suggestions rejected. quite impressive record.

Comment: I personally don't have issues, but my point is If he earn 2000 rep in site like ours then he will be in top 100 users overall , and may be he don't know magento well enough. And also his edits  dont improve the post he just search for possible common  typo mistakes and edit those typos just like `adress` instead of `address`

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala i give him credit finding these kind mistake for edit. Still best reviewer decide that it is okay or not. Or moderator can  decide that. user had 60 edit suggestions and all  approved.

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala there are many like this in top 100 user so don't worry about that.

Answer (score 4):

> And earning from edit only also not good Because from editing you are
>   not providing new things to community.

I agree with everything except above line in this thread. I believe he still contributes to the community as he can. It is obvious that the content become more readable. What we need to understand here is, he/she is spending his own time to review questions or answers and make the content more readable which I think is a good contribution itself.

A user who do such activity in our site with two primary mottos. He needs to increase his point or he want to make the content much better. Whatever be the intention, the result is more readable content which we always need to accept.

I know that if the user got very low reputation, then it will be queued in the edit section and we need to review it. It may feel some time messy for people who are reviewing those edits. But as a contributor to this community, I think we need to accept it without hesitations because I believe that is the job of each moderator in this community.

Answer (score 3):

I've answered a similar question a while ago on [Ask Ubuntu Meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/15465/8698). Although the question was worded differently, I think it is still valid here.

Basically, other than the daily cap of 200 rep, you cannot get more than 1k reputation from suggested edits. So if a user is only editing posts without asking or answering question, they will no be able to pass 1001 rep.

And as long as a user is doing constructive and helpful edits and they are not wasting reviewers time, that should be totally fine.

> Besides, reputation from edits are capped at 1000. So after your 500th edit suggestions, you will stop getting reputation.
>
> Also you do not get reputation from edits, but from "approved edit suggestions". Knowing this, when you reach 2k rep, you will no longer be able to suggest edits on posts, instead you will be able to edit them without waiting for someone to review them. This will stop you from receiving the 2 rep per edit suggestion.
>
> However you would still be able to receive 2 rep from edit suggestion on tag wikis until 20k.

Comment: It's a shame this is scored so low. I think it does a better job than any of the other answers at actually answering the question. I would combine it with [what Julien said](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1099/)--since edit suggestions are reviewed, it's on the reviewers to prevent terrible, just-trying-to-get-rep junk edits from getting through--to be complete.

Comment: @Pops I don't mind merging, but I don't have enough rep to edit meta posts. And we can't offer edit suggestions here.

Comment: @Pops yes Dan is right partially as he give me answer for the reputation limit for edit, but still my question for daily limit if user edit 100 post daily and has no rights for direct editing he will waste 300 users time, so if he waste 300 users time then edit should be more meaningful then just one spelling change

Answer (score 1):

I think its not good for website to gaining this type of reputation and for user too who are working hard to gain the reputation.

Its good for the website on the basis of content, But not good on the basis of website value.

If some/all are doing the same thing and gaining reputation then there is no value of it's reputation and we will loose good user from the site.

We have to prevent this type of reputation gaining technique to make standard of the site and its reputation.

> Recommending to allow max 20 reputation on edit in a day for a user.
>   After that he/she can edit but not gain reputation.